# Is it OK to say Havdala before Arvit?

Tags: havdalah, maariv, motzei-shabbos

Is it 100% permissible *lechatchila* to say Havdala before arvit on Motzae Shabbat or Yom Tov, if one is going to pray arvit late, for example, if one wants to go to a distant synagogue from his house?

What are the sources for the answer?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes it appears to be permitted

[Shulchan Aruch Harav (293:1)](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3447083/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-293-Laws-Governing-Evening-Service-on-Motzaei-Shabbos.htm) writes

> as soon as three stars can be seen next to each other, it is
>   permitted to recite Havdalah and perform labors [forbidden on Shabbos]
>   even though one has yet to recite the Evening Service

but see [here](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/not-doing-melacha-till-after-maariv/) that

> every meticulous person is to delay doing any [Biblical] Melacha until
>   the congregation has recited the Seder Kedusha after Maariv

(meaning you should wait a few minutes before doing melacha)

and [here](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/the-general-laws-2/) that

> some Poskim [Tehila Ledavid] however rule it is always proper to first
>   Daven Maariv and then do Havdala in order to follow the set order that
>   the Sages established.

---

[dinonline writes](http://dinonline.org/2011/12/09/havdalah-before-maariv/) (the question is asked on *sha’as hadchak* a time of need, but the end of the answer applies to all situations:

> The enactment of havdalah includes two parts: One havdalah in davening
>   and the other on a cup of wine.
>
> There is no specific order for the two parts, the Gemara mentioning
>   that somebody who made havdalah in davening must also make havdalah on
>   the wine (because this was the original enactment), and somebody who
>   made havdalah on wine must also add the havdalah insert in davening
>   (because this is part of the motzaei shabbos prayer).
>
> [...]
>
> **Therefore, it is fine, certainly where there is a need, to make havdalah before davening Maariv.**

---

R Yosef Weitzen writes [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3515)

> You can make Havdalah before Ma'ariv in such a situation [guests need to leave immediately]. You are
>   obliged to drink the wine and you do not have to repeat Havdalah after
>   Ma'ariv.

See also [here](http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/alonparash/print.asp?id=25806&kod=&modul=11&codeClient=58)

I personally think it is especially fine if it allows you to pray with a *minyan* later on vs. pray on your own at the end of shabbat/yom tov.